# Android - How to take an EditText (numbers) then convert it to an integer to use it for math?

Tags: java, android, integer, textview, android-edittext

I am wondering how to take an EditText area that the user can enter a number in, then make it an integer so it can be used in the program for adding, subtracting, dividing, etc. Basicaly I need the test the enter to be able to be used in a calculator which will be within the code and then it needs to be put into a TextView or string so the final answer can be seen by the user.

More info:
I have three EditText areas and the user has to fill in all three then press "equals" and it will tell them the answer, all the math and such needs to be in the code so the user just enters information and doesn't actually calculate anything.
Thanks for the help, please ask me if you need any more info.

The best way to do this and the code would help me a lot.

I have added the code that was suggested but I still get an error on parseInt and I still need to add a button to calculate the numbers entered in the EditText areas. How would I do this? Sorry I am fairly to Java and Android development.

```
             package com.example.one;


             import com.example.one.R;

             import android.app.Activity;
             import android.content.Intent;
             import android.os.Bundle;
             import android.text.Editable;
             import android.view.View;
             import android.widget.Button;
             import android.widget.EditText;

             public class monthlyp extends Activity{

         @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.monthlyp);


   EditText editone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editone);
   EditText editoneValue = (EditText) editone.getText();
   int editoneNum = Integer.parseInt(editoneValue);

    }
   ;

   }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, get an instance of the EditText:

```
EditText myEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
```

Then get the string that is currently being displayed:

```
String myEditValue = myEdit.getText().toString();
```

Then parse it for an integer:

```
int myEditNum = Integer.parseInt(myEditValue);
```

Comment: "**String myEditValue = myEdit.getText();**" - the `getText()` method of `EditText` returns an object of type `Editable` you need to use `toString()` to get the actual text.

Comment: Thank you very much. To display the final result to the user after they've pressed a button like "Equals" would I want to convert the integer back to like a string or TextView? I know I can use the integer for the math part of my program/app but i'm not sure how to then release the answer of what was calculated back to the user after they've pressed a button.

Comment: Austin, after you've calculated the final result, just use the .setText(result) method (I'm assuming you're using a TextView). Don't worry about converting the integer result to a string.

Comment: You should be careful not to get over Integer.MAX_VALUE in EditText or you will get NumberFormatException.

Answer (score 3):

You have to change, in the property of your EditText, the `Input type`. For numbers, you have three choice: `number`, `numberSigned` or `numberDecimal`. 
It depends on what you want.

Then if you want to convert your string on your EditText to an integer, you can do:

```
int value = new Integer(myEditText.getText().toString()).intValue;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
EditText myEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext1);

String myEditValue = myEdit.getText().toString();

int myEditNum = Integer.parseInt(myEditValue);

myEditNum.setText(textOut1);
```

I am using the above to get user input as a number format. However when I try to display the int myEditNum in a TextView(textOut1) using the setText() method I get an error for the setText method (saying: ''Cannot invoke setText(TextView) on the primitive type int'').

I also tried (below) to convert int myEditNum to a String and then display it to a TextView but still doesn't work as I get the folloing error for the setText method: ''The method setText(TextView) is undefined for the type String''.
EditText myEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext1);

```
String myEditValue = myEdit.getText().toString();

int myEditNum = Integer.parseInt(myEditValue);


String texting = Integer.toString(myEditNum);

texting.setText(textOut1);
```

Why does this happen and how do I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
myEdit.setText(myEditValue);
```

`myEditValue` is the String version of `myEditNum`.