# Parsing an integer value in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am trying to get integer value entered in `EditText` by user.

```
EditText eTextValue=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.eId); 
String eTextString=eTextValue.getText().toString();
int eTextValue1=Integer.parseInt(eTextString);
```

But unluckily I am getting,

> unable to parse 9827328 as integer.

I have tried using `Integer.valueOf` instead of `Integer.parseInt` but again I am getting the same exception.

I have even used `Long` datatype to store value instead of `int` type datatype but nothing seems to be working.Any help over this will be highly appreciated. 
I have gone through all these links [unable to parse ' ' as integer in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10469986/unable-to-parse-as-integer-in-android) , [Parsing value from EditText](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CEoQFjAC&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6948735/android-how-to-take-an-edittext-numbers-then-convert-it-to-an-integer-to-use&ei=5q7ZUMfJAsH9rAeVwIHIBA&usg=AFQjCNF-DGe7XG98RTa5oXTwkyRdF-WBuw&sig2=nvxTGH_AQRMZCDlhSLt5KQ&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.bmk)...but nothing seems to be working all of them are landing me in exception.

Comment: Can you post your Exception Stacktrace?

Comment: The number you enter may have leading and/or trailing white-spaces. Try using the `trim()` method.

Comment: Try with android:inputType="number" in xml.Also see..  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903515/how-do-i-return-an-int-from-edittext-android  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709253/converting-a-string-to-an-integer-android

Comment: Thanks Ridoy your solution works fine for me.I very much impressed by the intelligence of Android when it does not let the user enter any other value than Integer in EditText to avoid exception.

Answer (score 4):

You are using `eTextValue` as a variable name for two different things (an int and an EditText).  You cant do that and expect it to work properly.  Change one or the other and it should work better.

Answer (score 0):

```
int id;
id=Integer.parseInt(ed.getText().toString());
```

Comment: have you change variable names of edittext and int varible? its working at my place

Comment: Yes I tried but the only solution works in my place is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709253/converting-a-string-to-an-integer-android..

Answer (score 0):

Try by entering the following in the XML File under the corresponding EditText element.

android:inputType="number"

Hope this should get you pass the exception.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether the string you are parsing is an integer. Try this code:

```
if (IsInteger(eTextString)
   int eTextValue1=Integer.parseInt(eTextString);
```

and add this function:

```
public static boolean IsInteger(String s)
{
   if (s == null || s.length() == 0) return false;
   for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
   {
      if (Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 10) < 0)
         return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

I hope this helps